# What is the factorization algebra/space of an affine W algebra?

Tags: factorization, vertex-algebras, affine-grassmannian, w-algebras

The affine vertex algebra $V_k(\mathfrak{g})$ factorizes, i.e. comes from a factorisation space, the Beilinson Drinfeld Grassmannian. Similarly, lattice vertex algebras have a factorization analogue.

**Question:** Let $e\in\mathfrak{g}$ be nilpotent. Is there a nice description of the factorisation algebra associated to the affine W algebra $\mathcal{W}_k(\mathfrak{g},e)$, e.g. as coming from a factorisation space? References would be especially appreciated.

Comment: This is an open question. I'd look into recent work of Sam Raskin and not so recent by Sasha Braverman on Zastava spaces